# Using IBM Watson Text-To-Speech in a purely front-end setting

Tags: reactjs, ibm-watson, web-frontend

I would like to be able to send a string to IBM Watson TTS (text-to-speech) from my react component, i.e. without server-side code. The motivation is to reduce file transfers. All the examples I found (e.g. [this](https://github.com/IBM/text-to-speech-code-pattern)) require a Node.js server. Is there a fundamental reason that makes accessing Watson services from the code that runs in a browser impossible?

Comment: I havn't used ibm watson, but i'm guessing you need an api key to use it? If so, that's the reason it needs to be done server side: to keep the api key private.

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes, you do. But why can't I keep the api key safe with the front-end approach? For example, I could store the api key in the backend database and receive it from the server over https when the page loads. This way it will never appear in the code...

Comment: It's trivially easy for someone to open the dev tools in their browser and go to the network tab to see any traffic for a page. So if the browser makes a call to ibm's servers, that call will be visible in the network tab, including any query params or request headers like the api key.

Comment: @NicholasTower Can't the request to ibm's servers be sent (POST) over http**s**? (in which case it should appear encrypted, shouldn't it?)

Comment: Yes, the bytes are encrypted when they're sent over the wire. But your computer is the one crafting the message; it knows what it's sending. The issue isn't someone intercepting your packets and figuring out the api key, the issue is that in order to create those packets in the first place, your browser knows the api key already.

Comment: @NicholasTower In my case, each user of my app has his own api key and these keys are stored together with the authentication details of the users. This way, the front-end can send the api key to ibm's servers only while the user is signed in. Is this scenario not safe either?

Comment: If they log in and your code makes a call to IBM's servers, they can go to the network tab, find that call, and copy/paste the api key. Then they can use that api key in their own code, or post it on reddit, or do whatever they want with it. They may need to log in to trigger that first call, but after that the api key is just a string with no security.

Comment: @NicholasTower The users of my app deal with IBM directly and are charged by IBM for the TTS services. They receive the API key from IBM and enter it into my app. My app only adds some convenient features and charges a small flat monthly fee.

Answer (score 0):

While the reason is explained in the comments to the question (thanks @Nicholas Tower!), it seems that what I want to achieve is possible. Namely, IBM Watson employs the mechanism, whereby the backend can [request an IAM bearer token](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk#generating-bearer-tokens-using-api-key), which is only valid for a limited time. If I understand correctly, this token can be sent to the front-end, which in turn can use that token to make direct requests from the Watson service. I would be interested to know whether this is a standard practice.